# Confused about carrying variables and values from one method to another

Tags: c#, variables, inheritance, methods, out

I'm writing a simple practice program that allows the user to enter x/y coordinates for corners to various shapes, and then the program will tell the user basic facts about the shapes described (area, perimeter, etc) I created a class called TRIANGLE and I have a method in it that determines the length of each side (and assigns each side's length to their own variable) and the perimeter. I am trying to write another method that will compare those length variables to determine which side is the hypotenuse, the height, and the base. This is the code I have so far:

```
public void GetLength()
{
    string choice;
    double side1length = Math.Sqrt(((corner1.x - corner2.x) + (corner1.y - corner2.y) * (corner1.x - corner2.x) + (corner1.y - corner2.y)));
    double side2length = Math.Sqrt(((corner2.x - corner3.x) + (corner2.y - corner3.y) * (corner2.x - corner3.x) + (corner2.y - corner3.y)));
    double side3length = Math.Sqrt(((corner3.x - corner1.x) + (corner3.y - corner1.y) * (corner3.x - corner1.x) + (corner3.y - corner1.y)));
    Console.WriteLine("Which side do you want the length of? (first, second, third, perimeter)");
    choice = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (choice)
    {
        case "first":
            Console.Write($"The first side is {length1} units long");
            break;
        case "second":
            Console.Write($"The second side is {length2} units long");
            break;
        case "third":
            Console.Write($"The third side is {length3} units long");
            break;
        case "perimeter":
            Console.Write($"The perimeter is {length1 + length2 + length3}");
            break;
    }
}

public void GetArea()
{
    double hypotenuse, height, Base;
    if (side1length > side2length)
        if (side1length > side3length)
            hypotenuse = length1;
}
```

Did I need to use the out keyword with `GetLength()` method? is the problem the way I am trying access the variables in the `GetArea()` method? Is it both? Did I completely break the inheritance rules? What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: `GetArea()` never calls or scopes `GetLength()`, so how do you expect it to use its variable values?

Answer (score 0):

`GetArea()` never calls `GetLength()`, and its variables are scoped as `private`, so there's no way `GetArea()` can use them. Either use `out` parameters, or scope the variables as private to the **class**, and not the the method:

```
    private double side1length;
    private double side2length;
    private double side3length;

    public void GetLength()
    {
        string choice;
        side1length = ...;
        side2length = ...;
        side3length = ...;
        ...
    }
    public void GetArea()
    {
        GetLength();

        // Now you can use the variables here
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here you have written the local variables namely side1length,side2length,...and so on int the GetLength() method, so you cannot use them in the GetArea() method.
You should first read this, and try again for the solution.
https://docs.thunderstone.com/site/vortexman/variable_scope_global_vs_local.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `GetLength()` is never been called, thus none of `side*length` will be calculated.

Secondly, `side*length` are local variables, you'd better look at variable scope first.

There are several ways of solving your problem, Koby answered one. You can also use `out` if you like, but remember to declare the variables before calling `GetLength()`

```
public void GetLength(out double side1length, out double side2length, out double side3length) {
    // ...
}

public void GetArea() {
    double side1length, side2length, side3length;
    GetLength(out side1length, out side2length, out side3length);
    // ...
}
```

You can also declare a struct / class and return as a variable. Below is an example of using struct.

```
public struct SideLengths {
    public double side1;
    public double side2;
    public double side3;
}
public SideLengths GetLength() {
    SideLengths sl;
    sl.side1 = Math.Sqrt(((corner1.x - corner2.x) + (corner1.y - corner2.y) * (corner1.x - corner2.x) + (corner1.y - corner2.y)));
    // ...
    return sl;
}
public void GetArea() {
    SideLengths sl = GetLength();
    // use sl.side1 instead side1length in your original code
}
```

Furthermore, if it was me, I wouldn't put interaction in the functions. It would be better to ask user interaction in the "main" function rather than individual utilities functions. For example:

```
public double GetLength(string which) {
    double retVal;
    // calculating length
    return retVal;
}
static void Main() {
    // other code
    Console.WriteLine("Which side do you want the length of? (first, second, third, perimeter)");
    choice = Console.ReadLine();
    double length = GetLength(choice);
    // print out the length
}
```

This is still not the best practise, but is better than yours at this moment. However, I would leave you at this stage as apparently you are a beginner and it could mess up your mind if you're pushed too deep.

Finally, please consider a better practice in naming variables.